Z-Buffer map dosen't reflect real distance
I have been writing a script that filters points based on the depth map (Z-buffer map).
The idea here is that I use Blender API to get depth:
co_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, camera, world_position)
co_2d.z # is used as the depth of the current point

and afterwards, I'm comparing if this point is visible and not overlapped by anything else.
For some reason, I got huge values of the depth map. Why could such behavior appear?
Discrepancy at pixel (989, 534): Generated = 3.1325, Compositor = 10000000000.0000
# Generated value is from world_to_camera_view and Compositor is a depth map

UPDATED
Here is the wireframe of the scene:

Result of the 3D point distance to camera and depth buffer:
Discrepancy at pixel (965, 569): Generated Depth = 17.8477, Compositor Depth = 16.3513
Discrepancy at pixel (422, 568): Generated Depth = 99.0878, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000
Discrepancy at pixel (1643, 314): Generated Depth = 66.5391, Compositor Depth = 21.7443
Discrepancy at pixel (348, 204): Generated Depth = 37.0706, Compositor Depth = 21.7557
Discrepancy at pixel (1662, 854): Generated Depth = 22.3911, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000
Discrepancy at pixel (262, 778): Generated Depth = 22.0798, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000
Discrepancy at pixel (256, 774): Generated Depth = 27.8770, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000
Discrepancy at pixel (1660, 834): Generated Depth = 27.8769, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000
Discrepancy at pixel (965, 549): Generated Depth = 27.8770, Compositor Depth = 16.1918
Discrepancy at pixel (1258, 150): Generated Depth = 27.8769, Compositor Depth = 10000000000.0000

Annotated render of it, where reds are on foreground and blues on background:


Are these huge values in areas where the background is visible? Because the world background has no fixed distance to the camera, it is theoretically infinitely far away. Apart from that I do not really understand what you are doing there, sorry.

I saw the topic here, that 10000000000.0000, in general, tells that the ray has not collided with anything and this value should be treated as inf.
But as I experienced, on some angles of camera all distances are calculated properly, but with some slight rotation-reposition, it breaks.

Okay, so I was not aware of this thing: Set bpy.data.images.pixels from top left instead of bottom left
As turned out, bpy.data.images.pixels measures their coordinates relatively from the bottom-left corner, but py_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view measure them from the top-left corner of the image :)
That's why I got the wrong calculation results.
